# How to show next month in php

Tags: php

```
$date ="2018-02-15";
$next_month = date('$date', strtotime('+1 month');

echo "$next_month";
```

I want the output as `"2018-03-15"`;
But this code not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strtotime`

```
$date ="2018-02-15";
$time = strtotime($date);
$next_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));

echo $next_month;
```

The result will be:

```
2018-03-15
```

Doc: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$date ="2018-04-22";
$next_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.' +1 month'));
echo "$next_month";
```